# Remove curly bracket from a string

Tags: php

I have a string as :

```
 $string={"name":"simon","age":"23"}
```

I want to remove the curly bracket from the string.Output should be like this :

```
$string="name":"simon","age":"24"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the curly brackets occur as first and last characters of your string, you can try this:

```
$string = substr($string, 1, -1);
```

Comment: Beware of Your Common Sense guy :) He has made a lot of foes here because he down votes most of the times he stays on this site :P

Answer (score 9):

That's JSON, I would prefer using `json_decode` and convert it to an array:

```
$myArray = json_decode($string, true);
print_r($myArray);
```

If you still want that, you can do:

```
$string = '{"name":"simon","age":"23"}';
echo trim($string, '{}'); // "name":"simon","age":"23"
```

Comment: yes that's json.But i dont want to use json_decode.Want to do string manipulation.Any sugession?

Comment: @Toby you have to address a recipient with @

Comment: @YourCommonSense i can use json_decode..just as a different way i am trying to use it.nothing else.json_decode is great..

Comment: One thing to watch out for is `echo trim($string, '{}');` will remove all trailing `}`. So if you have associative arrays or array-like objects inside the JSON, then you will have too many trailing braces stripped off.

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_replace('/[{}]/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to remove the curly braces if they are the first and last characters (and you don't want to remove those characters *unless* they are curly braces) then you can use this:

```
preg_replace('/^{(.*)}$/', '$1', $string);
```